# New Problems Installing ATI-Catalyst driver in 12.04 LTS

Tags: ati, fglrx, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers in 12.04 LTS?:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts)

This is relation [to a previous question I asked here that was described][1] as an exact duplicate.

I started following the instruction given and I am getting below messages in terminal

> Reading state information... Done 
>   E: Unable to locate package dkgcc1
>   E: Unable to locate package libc6-i386ms 
>   E: Unable to locate package> lib32

[Here is the full terminal transcript][2]

I am not technical but if its any help my machine is 64bit

**From Ubuntu Community Documentation (For v 12.4)**

Ubuntu 12.04 Precise:

> sudo sh amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg
>   Ubuntu/precise
>
> If it is required, a package manager window will open and install some
>   dependencies and after a while create the following four .deb
>   packages:
>
> fglrx_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   fglrx-amdcccle_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   fglrx-dev_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.de
>
> Note: It will also create a file called
>   fglrx-installer_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.changes. If you wish you can read
>   this file to know the changes that have been effected through AMD/ATI
>   Catalyst 12.3 and related information.
>
> ```
> To install the created .deb files, type:
> ```
>
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
>
> Note: In case any of the packages are broken, open Synaptic Package
>   Manager and go to Edit -> Fix Broken Packages. In case you are new to
>   Ubuntu, broken here means that some dependent packages are not yet
>   installed. Once you sort out the issue as indicated above through the
>   Synaptic Package Manager, the problem of broken packages should be
>   resolved.
>
> ```
> Continuing with the installation, type:
> ```
>
> sudo aticonfig --initial
>
> After this command, reboot your system. If all is right, the fglrx
>   driver that corresponds to AMD/ATI Catalyst 12.3 will be installed and
>   working on your system. To confirm the drivers are working open a
>   terminal and type:
>
> fglrxinfo
>
> You should get an output similar to the following:
>
> display: :0  screen: 0 OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices,
>   Inc. OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series
>   OpenGL version string: 3.3.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
>
> Any help welcome
>
> [1]:
>   [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts)   [2]: http://pastebin.com/r5PgYEVT

Comment: Problem Resolved, the answer is in the original [question here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts/126513#126513